# On modern fighter aircraft, why do most carry a rotary cannon when they tend to have little use against aircraft?

Tags: fighter

I understand that in multirole or strike aircraft the cannon has a CAS use, but on a purely fighter aircraft, does the benefit of a fallback weapon outweigh the handicap of added weight?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is highly opinion-based and should be closed.

But here are my $0.02

Historically there were attempts to remove cannons but turns out too early: Missiles are not that good. The benefit of fallback weapon indeed outweight the weight.

> [MIG21 VS RF-4C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Dark_Gene#Detailed%20incident)
>
> One instance of combat during Project Dark Gene was an engagement on
>   November 28, 1973 between an RF-4C aircraft piloted by IIAF Major
>   Shokouhnia and backseater USAF Colonel John Saunders and a Soviet
>   MiG-21 flown by Captain Gennadii N. Eliseev. **The Soviet pilot fired
>   two Vympel K-13 missiles at the Iranian aircraft, failing to destroy
>   it. He was ordered from ground control to press his attack at any
>   cost, and with his cannon jammed after the first shot,[8] he continued
>   by ramming into the Iranian aircraft and losing his life in the
>   process.** He struck the RF-4C's tail assembly with his wing and then
>   flew into high ground. It was the first deliberate jet-to-jet ramming
>   by a Soviet aircraft during an interception, a practice common in the
>   propeller age of World War II. Eliseev was posthumously awarded as a
>   Hero of the Soviet Union.[3][9] The crew of the RF-4C aircraft were
>   captured by Soviet ground forces and released after 16 days.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II)[10]

US military reached the same conclusion around the same time as well, to add cannons to [F-4 Phantom II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II).

Maybe now is the time to rethink this question again after 40+ years advancement of AA missiles. But if you ask the pilot, for the same weight, do they want fuel, gun+ammo, or nothing? A significant portion, if not the majority, would pick the gun I guess.

A lot of fighter pilots, or even astronauts, carry pistols. How useful is that?

Comment: It's not just the reliability of missiles that's a reason for guns, it's also their limited number. Once your precious 2-4 missiles (the normal warload of most aircraft) is exhausted, you're now useless except as a pair of eyes. The gun extends that to several more engagements. And do remember that it's normal practice to fire missiles in pairs to make avoiding the attack harder.

Comment: If you seriously think it should be closed, you're saying it shouldn't be answered, and you say because POB which tends for VLQ answers from low-rep users . So why did you answer it at all?

Comment: @Nij For fun, obviously.